# Who to get the sum of two arrays?

Tags: javascript

I want to sum two arrays : `num_array` and `num2_array` using `for` loops like this for example : `num_array[1] + num2_array[5]`, `num_array[2] + num2_array[4]` ...

This is what I've tried :

```
var num_array, num2_array;
var i, j, sum = 0;

for(i=0; i < 6; i++)
{
    num_array[i] = get_integer("NUMBER: ","");

    while(num_array[i] < 1 && num_array[i] > 500)
    {
        num_array[i] = get_integer("Enter a number inn limit of 1 to 500", 0);
    }
}

for(i=5; i >= 0; i--)
{
    num2_array[i] = num_array[i];
    show_message(num2_array[i]);
}
```

Comment: `while(num_array[i] < 1 && num_array[i] > 500)` will _never_ be true

Answer (score 0):

Refer this code

```
 var num_array,num2_array;
var sum=0;

  for(var i=0;i<num_array.length,i++){
    sum+=num_array[i]
  }
  for(var j=0;j<num2_array.length,j++){
    sum+=num_array[j]
  }
```